# How to enable a player to move freely in a 2D JavaFX game?

Tags: java, javafx

Context

I am making a top-down game in JavaFX. I have a standard setup with scene, ParallelCamera, a stage set to fullscreen, and I am using the AnimationTimer for gameloop. I render gameobjects directly with the GraphicsContext.drawImage()

The problem

When moving the player (and attached camera) to the sides, enough that they are in a space that was not visible on screen at the start of the game, all text nodes disappear and MouseEvent.getSceneX() stops working correctly (the returned value seems to be snapped to the initial rectangle of the screen).

What I have tried

Read JavaFX documentation and looked at example projects, but they all seem to dodge the feature of having a player that actually moves about. Any help to how this should be handled within the JavaFX world would be appreciated.

Below is a picture of the problem. The red line shows where the right edge of the screen is at the start of the game. It matches up with where the text node is cut off. The text reads "FPS: 120". If I move back to the left, the text displays as it should. The same line coincides with where the MouseEvent.getSceneX() stops working as expected.

[image]

Code for camera movement:

```
public static void moveCamera(double x, double y)
{
    // Moves the UI-group by the same amount so it stays in the camera view
    camera.relocate(camera.getLayoutX() + x, camera.getLayoutY() + y);
    uiElements.relocate(uiElements.getLayoutX() + x, uiElements.getLayoutY() + y);
}
```

The uiElements is a Group node which is parent to the fpstext, the idea is to move that whole node as much as the camera so all UI stays fixed in the camera view.

Code for drawing objects:

```
public void update(double deltaTime)
{
    // Rendering
    if (sprite == null)
    {
        this.setSprite(img_src);
    }
    else
    {
        Main.gc.drawImage(sprite, tf.xPosition(), tf.yPosition(), tf.width(), tf.height());
    }
}
```

This update function is on a "RendererComponent" owned by an "Entity", these are called from a loop in the main gameloop. Objects rendered in this way is not subject to the same clipping as the fpsText.

Comment: Please include some code so we can see how you manage the camera movement and the contents of drawImage. I suspect that the camera/map offset is not fully being taken into account.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I added some relevant code. Is there a way I can open the question back up?

Comment: There is a Reopen button at the bottom of your question next to edit, others will need to approve it though. Note, if the `uiElements` are separate from the other parts (Not related to the camera?), then there would be no need to move them, just draw them in exactly the same place every time, or draw them to a glass pane (transparent layer above the GraphicsContext), or directly to the GraphicsContext if it only renders the visible part of the screen?

Comment: I wanted the fpsCounter to just be a Text object so I can set and forget, and it doesn't directly have to know about the position of the player, but I tried changing the class managing the fpsCounter to fillText directly on canvas instead. The issue of clipping is gone, although a nasty bleed effect appears when moving now, I might be able to work that out though. Do you have any suggestions on the MouseEvent.getSceneX() not working as I expect when clicking beyond the line in the original image?

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: For game development with JavaFX you might also want to have a look at FXGL: https://github.com/AlmasB/FXGL

Comment: The project in question is for a uni class, but I will look into that for hobby projects. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While making a minimal demo I was able to come up with a way to fix the problem. The MouseEvent.getSceneX() was always returning a point relative to the window view. This still seems strange, since the MouseEvent.getTarget() returns the canvas, which is 4 times larger than the window size. Nevertheless, in calculating the point of a click, instead of doing just getSceneX(), I did `(owner.tf().xPosition() + owner.tf().width()/2) - Main.WINDOW_WIDTH/2 + screenX`. This returns values as I would expect.